# How to change x-axis label intervals for a datetime series in R

Tags: r, datetime, plot, posixct

I have created a plot with a time series on the x-axis and count values on the y-axis. I would like to know how to change the intervals on the time series x-axis so that the time interval is every 3 hours. I am not sure how to apply a simple method like at=seq(0,100,10) to a time series. Secondly, is it possible to use text labels for times that are not represented in your dataset? i.e. the example data below are in 10-minute intervals starting at 09:29, but would it be possible to use time values on the x-axis that fall on the hour? I am assuming that the only way to do this would be to manually list the times in a text string but wondered whether I am missing anything? Any advise would be appreciated.

Example data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1396603740, 1396604340, 
1396604940, 1396605540, 1396606140, 1396606740, 1396607340, 1396607940, 
1396608540, 1396609140, 1396609740, 1396610340, 1396610940, 1396611540, 
1396612140, 1396612740, 1396613340, 1396613940, 1396614540, 1396615140, 
1396615740, 1396616340, 1396616940, 1396617540, 1396618140, 1396618740, 
1396619340, 1396619940, 1396620540, 1396621140, 1396621740, 1396622340, 
1396622940, 1396623540, 1396624140, 1396624740, 1396625340, 1396625940, 
1396626540, 1396627140, 1396627740, 1396628340, 1396628940, 1396629540, 
1396630140, 1396630740, 1396631340, 1396631940, 1396632540, 1396633140, 
1396633740, 1396634340, 1396634940, 1396635540, 1396636140, 1396636740, 
1396637340, 1396637940, 1396638540, 1396639140, 1396639740, 1396640340, 
1396640940, 1396641540, 1396642140, 1396642740, 1396643340, 1396643940, 
1396644540, 1396645140, 1396645740, 1396646340, 1396646940, 1396647540
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), count = c(46, 
45, 47, 43, 49, 46, 46, 44, 44, 44, 45, 49, 50, 46, 45, 43, 47, 
48, 48, 46, 47, 46, 46, 44, 46, 44, 45, 49, 44, 46, 44, 48, 44, 
42, 44, 50, 44, 44, 48, 43, 43, 46, 44, 49, 49, 44, 42, 45, 45, 
48, 46, 45, 46, 43, 40, 50, 39, 42, 48, 44, 44, 46, 43, 47, 46, 
41, 43, 43, 46, 48, 45, 48, 43, 42)), .Names = c("datetime", 
"count"), row.names = c(NA, -74L), class = "data.frame")

>head(df)
             datetime count
1 2014-04-04 09:29:00    46
2 2014-04-04 09:39:00    45
3 2014-04-04 09:49:00    47
4 2014-04-04 09:59:00    43
5 2014-04-04 10:09:00    49
6 2014-04-04 10:19:00    46
```

Example code (to plots all datetimes):

```
#Convert datetime character string to POSIXct format
df$datetime = as.POSIXct(strptime(df$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), tz="UTC")

plot(df$datetime, df$count, axes=FALSE)
axis(2,las=2)
axis.POSIXct(1, at=df$datetime, labels=format(df$datetime, “%H:%M")) #datetime format can be changed as desired
lines(df$datetime, df$count, col="grey22")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, let's correct your `axis.POSIXct` call:

```
axis.POSIXct(1, at=df$datetime, format="%H:%M")
```

Argument `format` let you define your time format without having to format each label one by one. The `at` argument is the one we are going to use to define where the ticks will be.

First you can define a sequence of date using `seq` applied to POSIXt objects (see `?seq.POSIXt`) where the argument `by` can be provided with custom names such as `"3 hours"`:

> A character string, containing one of "sec", "min", "hour", "day", "DSTday", "week", "month" or "year". This can optionally be preceded by a (positive or negative) integer and a space, or followed by "s".

Therefore:

```
seq(df$datetime[1], tail(seq$datetime,1), by="3 hours")
# [1] "2014-04-04 09:29:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 12:29:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 15:29:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 18:29:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 21:29:00 UTC"
```

Now to make the sequence starts at a full hour, one need to use `round` (see `?round.POSIXt`):

```
round(df$datetime[1], "hour")
# [1] "2014-04-04 09:00:00 UTC"
seq(round(df$datetime[1],"hour"), tail(df$datetime,1), by="3 hours")
# [1] "2014-04-04 09:00:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 12:00:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 15:00:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 18:00:00 UTC" "2014-04-04 21:00:00 UTC"
```

To summarize, your code becomes:

```
df <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1396603740, 1396604340, 1396604940, 1396605540, 1396606140, 1396606740, 1396607340, 1396607940, 1396608540, 1396609140, 1396609740, 1396610340, 1396610940, 1396611540, 1396612140, 1396612740, 1396613340, 1396613940, 1396614540, 1396615140, 1396615740, 1396616340, 1396616940, 1396617540, 1396618140, 1396618740, 1396619340, 1396619940, 1396620540, 1396621140, 1396621740, 1396622340, 1396622940, 1396623540, 1396624140, 1396624740, 1396625340, 1396625940, 1396626540, 1396627140, 1396627740, 1396628340, 1396628940, 1396629540, 1396630140, 1396630740, 1396631340, 1396631940, 1396632540, 1396633140, 1396633740, 1396634340, 1396634940, 1396635540, 1396636140, 1396636740, 1396637340, 1396637940, 1396638540, 1396639140, 1396639740, 1396640340, 1396640940, 1396641540, 1396642140, 1396642740, 1396643340, 1396643940, 1396644540, 1396645140, 1396645740, 1396646340, 1396646940, 1396647540), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), count = c(46, 45, 47, 43, 49, 46, 46, 44, 44, 44, 45, 49, 50, 46, 45, 43, 47, 48, 48, 46, 47, 46, 46, 44, 46, 44, 45, 49, 44, 46, 44, 48, 44, 42, 44, 50, 44, 44, 48, 43, 43, 46, 44, 49, 49, 44, 42, 45, 45, 48, 46, 45, 46, 43, 40, 50, 39, 42, 48, 44, 44, 46, 43, 47, 46, 41, 43, 43, 46, 48, 45, 48, 43, 42)), .Names = c("datetime", "count"), row.names = c(NA, -74L), class = "data.frame")
plot(df$datetime, df$count, axes=FALSE)
axis(2,las=2)
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(from=round(df$datetime[1],"hour"),
                       to=tail(df$datetime,1),
                       by="3 hours"),
                format="%H:%M")
lines(df$datetime, df$count, col="grey22")
```

[image]

Comment: @ plannapus. Excellent, this is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you SO much!